# Which scriptures describe swayambhu linga lakshanas (signs) and what are those?

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas, shiva-lingam, agamas

I have a small book called Shiva Tattva PradipikA which discusses the various facts associated with Lord Shiva by quoting from scriptures like Vedas, Upanishads, Puranas, Agamas.

In it we find the mention of several kinds of Shiva Lingas like Swayambhu, Bana, Indra, Vaishnava, Gola, Arsha, Raudra, Manasa, Shivanabhi and many others.

The book also discusses the signs that determine some of these lingas.

For Swayambhu Lingas (self manifested lingas) following are the lakshanas (or signs) mentioned:

> **NAnacchidrasamAdhritam NAnAvarnasamanvitam | Adrishtamulam Yalingam
>   Karkasam Bhuvi Drisyathe || Tallinganthu Swayambhutamatharam
>   Lakshyanachyutam |** Swayambhulingamityuktam Taccha NAnAvidha Matam ||
>   ShankhAbhamastakam Lingam Vaishnavam TadudAhritam | PadmAbhamastakam
>   BrAhmam ChatrAbham Shatrumuchyathe ||........
>
> ...........
>
> **The Lingas which have many pours or holes, which have different
>   colors, whose root is deep within the earth and can't be seen. which
>   are rough are called Swayambhulingas. The Lingas which are deprived of
>   these signs are lakshanachyuta.** Swayambhulingas are of various kinds.
>   The head of which is like a conch shell is called a Vaishnavalinga. If the head
>   is like a lotus then its  known as BrAhmalinga. If head is like an
>   umbrella is called the Aindralinga and so on...

1) From which scripture the above verses are taken?

2) Do Puranas like Shiva. Linga etc discuss the various kinds of Swayambhu lingas and do they mention their signs? If yes, what are those signs?